# Can I Install Any Amount Of SSD Drive On My SATA-3 Port?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata

I'm planning to replace HDD in my Lenovo Ideapad 330 15IKB laptop with an SSD and want to install 512GB SSD.

But when I checked the [Lenovo Ideapad 330 15IKB manual](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/330-14ikb_81da_g2_330-15ikb_81dc_de_330touch-15ikb_81dh_81dj_hmm_201803.pdf), it says it can support up to 256GB of SSD only.

[image: Pic Here]

Is it true that motherboards can only accept limited amount of SSD storage?

I was planning following things:

1. Take out HDD and install SSD with OS.
2. Purchase a Caddy and Install HDD in optical drive slot.

What you think?

Comment: What the table shows are merely capacity options for the different models, not what they can support up to. There will hardly be any problem as long as it's no larger than 2TB.

Answer (score 0):

The shown capacities are the ones that the manufacturer supplies, not the biggest upgrade you can do. That being said, any supported HDD capacity should be OK for SSD as well (since there is no limitation based on type of storage in BIOS/ Operating system) - i.e. you can install a 2TB SSD without issues.

If you already have the OS on your laptop's HDD you can use a cloning software like Acronis True Image or Easeus Partition Master to move the data directly to the SSD and not re-install the OS and programs.

> Purchase a Caddy and Install HDD in optical drive slot.

Unless your laptop has another SATA port then you can always purchase a USB3 caddy / external rack (~10€) and keep the original HDD as additional storage.